# UE4 RPCs Function _Implementation not called

Tags: unreal-engine4

To get Started, I'm sorry but I don't speak English very well.

My .h:

```
UFUNCTION()
void AttachToPlayer(USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh, const FName &SocketName);

UFUNCTION(Server, Reliable, WithValidation)
void ServerAttachToPlayer(USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh, const FName &SocketName);

virtual void ServerAttachToPlayer_Implementation(USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh, const FName &SocketName);

virtual bool ServerAttachToPlayer_Validate(USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh, const FName &SocketName);
```

My cpp:

```
void ABagPlayer::AttachToPlayer(USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh, const FName &SocketName)
{
    if (Role == ROLE_Authority)
    {
         GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Red, TEXT("TEST"));
    }
    else
    {
        ServerAttachToPlayer(Mesh, SocketName);
    }
}


bool ABagPlayer::ServerAttachToPlayer_Validate(USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh, const FName &SocketName)
{
    return true;
}


void ABagPlayer::ServerAttachToPlayer_Implementation(USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh, const FName &SocketName)
{
    AttachToPlayer(Mesh, SocketName);
}
```

I do not understand why, when my client launches the function  "AttachToPlayer ", the function ' ServerAttachToPlayer_Implementaion ' is not called.
However, if it is the server that calls  "AttachToPlayer ", the function  "ServerAttachToPlayer_Implementaion " is called.

I've tried a lot of things, I'm pulling my hair!

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think you can send UObject through an RPC.

Comment: what's the version of UE4 you used? maybe a bug of engine